# Import Data model from XLSX file to Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler

Tags: excel, import, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I'm new to Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler and I'm trying to import a data model stored in an excel file that was used to import to powerAMC from Sybase.

(I have one tab for domains, one for tables, one for primary keys, one for scolumn, one for relations etc.)

I'm ok to transform this file but having this, I don't really want to enter all the model manually.

I found the tool "update with the previously exported XLS file" but I don't know witch XLS template to use. Also, I read that this could only be used to update tables and columns and not create them.

I hope some one will have a nice trick to do this :)

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

"update with the previously exported XLS file"

That's not for importing data models from Excel. That feature allows one to generate a report from an existing model to Excel, let users update it in Excel, and then suck the changes back in.

I think your best bet is to have a DDL file generated from the database, and then trying to import that.

Also, for what's it worth, the Data Modeler doesn't officially support Sybase. At best you'll get generic JDBC database SQL support.

If you're curious about the Excel import stuff, you can read my post on the feature [here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/sql-developer-data-modeler-v3-3-early-adopter-collaborative-design-via-excel/).

Comment: Thanks, we are now using an Oracle DB.
I'll look at your post.

Comment: Hi, I have read you Articles but I still can't figure out how to résolve my problem. Do you know if there is any way to importe a date model directly from excel ? (one tab for domains, one for tables, one for primary keys, one for column, one for relations etc.)

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Comment: No, we only support database imports, and Excel isn't a database - regardless of what some people might think.